# How to remove duplicate dictionary items by value in a list of dictionary items in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of about 5,000 dictionary items like so:

```
list_of_dicts = [

{'organization_name': 'OrgA', 'country': 'United States'},
{'organization_name': 'OrgA', 'country': None },
{'organization_name': 'OrgB', 'country': 'Finland'},
{'organization_name': 'OrgC', 'country': 'United States'}

]
```

I would like to remove duplicate dictionary items from this list. By "duplicates", I mean items that have the same value for 'organization_name'. For example, the first and second items are duplicates, but the first and fourth items are not duplicates.

What is a good way to accomplish this? Note that this is a one-time data cleaning exercise so the solution does not have to be super efficient.

Comment: Do you want to drop both OrgA dicts, or keep one?

Comment: Good point. I want to keep 1. So if there are 10 instances of the same item, I just want 1 to remain in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set to track what organizations you've seen, and only keep the dict if you haven't seen it before:

```
orgs = set()
kept_dicts = []
for d in list_of_dicts:
    org = d['organization_name']
    if org not in orgs:
        kept_dicts.append(d)
        orgs.add(org)
```

Comment: That worked very well. Thank you!